# Why does my provided argument value get replaced each time I run function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**My goal** is to have a user click on the provided buttons, with each button tied to a numeric value, and then have the total recalculate each time a button is clicked.

**My issue** is that each time a button is selected and the total is recalculated, one of the arguments to calculateTotalPrice is replaced with the default of 0. If values for both arguments (chosenStyle and chosenColours) are given, then I simply want the program to use the provided values (not the default values).

I want each category of button ("T-Shirt Style" and "# of Print Colours") to only add to the total once. For example, if button "Tee" is selected (a value of 10) and button "1" is selected (a value of 3), then the total should be 13.

If no button from each category has been selected yet, the program should assume a default value of 0. If both buttons have been selected, then the program should use the provided values (in the same example, totalPrice = 10 + 3 (13).

When I use the default values, only one of the button values is being applied. If I don't use default values, then the totalPrice gives me NaN each time it is calculated.

I feel like this should be pretty simple. Haha. I am a JavaScript newbie who has read through about 50 different online articles to find the best way to calculate the total, but to no avail.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
// Initialize totalPrice variable and display to user
var totalPrice = 0;
$('.total-price').html('Total Price = ' + '$' + totalPrice);

// Calculate total price
function calculateTotalPrice (chosenStyle = 0, chosenColours = 0) {
    totalPrice = chosenStyle + chosenColours;
    $('.total-price').html('Total Price = ' + '$' + totalPrice);
}


/* *** Complete T-Shirt Style steps *** */

var calculateStylePrice = function () {

    // Get selected T-Shirt Style button and store in variable
    var tshirtStyle = $(this);

    // Change style of selected button
    $(this).toggleClass('button--clicked');

    // Get selected T-Shirt Style value and store in variable
    var chosenStyle = $(this).val();

    // Initialize chosenStylePrice to hold price of chosen style
    var chosenStylePrice = 0;

    // Add price of selected T-Shirt Style to chosenStylePrice variable
    if (chosenStyle == 'tee') {
        chosenStylePrice = 10;
    }
    if (chosenStyle == 'ladies') {
        chosenStylePrice = 12;
    }
    if (chosenStyle == 'long') {
        chosenStylePrice = 14;
    }
    if (chosenStyle == 'hood') {
        chosenStylePrice = 30;
    }

    // Output selected T-Shirt Style to user
    $('.chosen-style').html('T-Shirt Style = ' + chosenStyle + ' ($' + chosenStylePrice + ')');

    // Add chosenStylePrice price to totalPrice
    calculateTotalPrice(chosenStylePrice);
};

// Bind calculateStylePrice click event to T-Shirt Style buttons
$('[id^=style]').on('click', calculateStylePrice);


/* *** Complete T-Shirt Style steps *** */

var calculateColoursPrice = function () {

    // Get selected # of Colours and store in variable
    var colourNumber = $(this);

    // Change style of selected button
    $(this).toggleClass('button--clicked');

    // Get selected # of Colours value and store in variable
    var chosenColours = $(this).val();

    // Initialize chosenStylePrice to hold price of chosen style
    var chosenColoursPrice = 0;

    // Add price of selected # of Colours to chosenColoursPrice variable
    if (chosenColours == 1) {
        chosenColoursPrice = 3;
    }
    if (chosenColours == 2) {
        chosenColoursPrice = 5;
    }
    if (chosenColours == 3) {
        chosenColoursPrice = 7;
    }
    if (chosenColours == 4) {
        chosenColoursPrice = 9;
    }
    if (chosenColours == 5) {
        chosenColoursPrice = 11;
    }
    if (chosenColours == 6) {
        chosenColoursPrice = 13;
    }

    // Output selected # of Colours to user
    $('.chosen-colours').html('# of Print Colours = ' + chosenColours + ' ($' + chosenColoursPrice + ')');

    // Add chosenColoursPrice price to totalPrice
    calculateTotalPrice(chosenColoursPrice);
};

// Bind calculateColoursPrice click event to # of Print Colours buttons
$('[id^=colour]').on('click', calculateColoursPrice);
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="options">
    <div class="option-container">
        <h3>T-Shirt Style</h3>
        <button id="style-tee" class="button button-rectangle" value="tee">Tee</button>
        <button id="style-ladies" class="button button-rectangle" value="ladies">Ladies</button>
        <button id="style-long" class="button button-rectangle" value="long">Long</button>
        <button id="style-hood" class="button button-rectangle" value="hood">Hood</button>
    </div><!--option-container-->

    <div class="option-container">
        <h3># of Print Colours</h3>
        <button id="colour-1" class="button button-circle" value="1">1</button>
        <button id="colour-2" class="button button-circle" value="2">2</button>
        <button id="colour-3" class="button button-circle" value="3">3</button>
        <button id="colour-4" class="button button-circle" value="4">4</button>
        <button id="colour-5" class="button button-circle" value="5">5</button>
        <button id="colour-6" class="button button-circle" value="6">6</button>
    </div><!--option-container-->

    <div class="option-container">
        <h3>Quantity</h3>
        <select id="quantity" class="button" name="quantity">
            <option value="10to14">10 to 14</option>
            <option value="15to19">15 to 19</option>
            <option value="20to24">20 to 24</option>
            <option value="25to29">25 to 29</option>
            <option value="30to39">30 to 29</option>
            <option value="40to49">40 to 49</option>
            <option value="50to74">50 to 74</option>
            <option value="75to99">75 to 99</option>
            <option value="100plus">100+</option>
        </select>
    </div><!--option-container-->
</div><!--options-->


<div class="quote">
<p class="chosen-style"></p>
<p class="chosen-colours"></p>
<p class="chosen-quantity"></p>
<p class="total-price"></p>
</div><!--quote-->
```

Comment: could you add your html code?

Comment: I just edited with my HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

```js
// Initialize totalPrice variable and display to user
var totalPrice = 0;
var chosenColoursPrice = 0;
var chosenStylePrice = 0;
$('.total-price').html('Total Price = ' + '$' + totalPrice);

// Calculate total price
function calculateTotalPrice () {
    totalPrice = chosenStylePrice + chosenColoursPrice;
    $('.total-price').html('Total Price = ' + '$' + totalPrice);
}


/* *** Complete T-Shirt Style steps *** */

var calculateStylePrice = function () {
    // Get selected T-Shirt Style button and store in variable
    var tshirtStyle = $(this);

    // Change style of selected button
    $(this).toggleClass('button--clicked');

    // Get selected T-Shirt Style value and store in variable
    var chosenStyle = $(this).text();

    // Initialize chosenStylePrice to hold price of chosen style
    chosenStylePrice = 0;

    // Add price of selected T-Shirt Style to chosenStylePrice variable
    if (chosenStyle == 'tee') {
        chosenStylePrice = 10;
    }
    if (chosenStyle == 'ladies') {
        chosenStylePrice = 12;
    }
    if (chosenStyle == 'long') {
        chosenStylePrice = 14;
    }
    if (chosenStyle == 'hood') {
        chosenStylePrice = 30;
    }

    // Output selected T-Shirt Style to user
    $('.chosen-style').html('T-Shirt Style = ' + chosenStyle + ' ($' + chosenStylePrice + ')');

    // Add chosenStylePrice price to totalPrice
    calculateTotalPrice(chosenStylePrice);
};

// Bind calculateStylePrice click event to T-Shirt Style buttons
$('[id^=style]').on('click', calculateStylePrice);


/* *** Complete T-Shirt Style steps *** */

var calculateColoursPrice = function () {

    // Get selected # of Colours and store in variable
    var colourNumber = $(this);

    // Change style of selected button
    $(this).toggleClass('button--clicked');

    // Get selected # of Colours value and store in variable
    var chosenColours = parseInt($(this).text());

    // Initialize chosenStylePrice to hold price of chosen style
    chosenColoursPrice = 0;

    // Add price of selected # of Colours to chosenColoursPrice variable
    if (chosenColours == 1) {
        chosenColoursPrice = 3;
    }
    if (chosenColours == 2) {
        chosenColoursPrice = 5;
    }
    if (chosenColours == 3) {
        chosenColoursPrice = 7;
    }
    if (chosenColours == 4) {
        chosenColoursPrice = 9;
    }
    if (chosenColours == 5) {
        chosenColoursPrice = 11;
    }
    if (chosenColours == 6) {
        chosenColoursPrice = 13;
    }

    // Output selected # of Colours to user
    $('.chosen-colours').html('# of Print Colours = ' + chosenColours + ' ($' + chosenColoursPrice + ')');

    // Add chosenColoursPrice price to totalPrice
    calculateTotalPrice();
};

// Bind calculateColoursPrice click event to # of Print Colours buttons
$('[id^=colour]').on('click', calculateColoursPrice);
```

```css
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="total-price">0</div>
        <a href="#" id="style-tee" class="button">tee</a>
        <a href="#" id="style-ladies" class="button">ladies</a>
        <a href="#" id="style-long" class="button">long</a>
        <a href="#" id="style-hood" class="button">hood</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="#" id="colour-1" class="button">1</a>
        <a href="#" id="colour-2" class="button">2</a>
        <a href="#" id="colour-3" class="button">3</a>
        <a href="#" id="colour-4" class="button">4</a>
        <a href="#" id="colour-5" class="button">5</a>
        <a href="#" id="colour-6" class="button">6</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="chosen-style"></div>
        <div class="chosen-colours"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think my original issue all along is that I was trying to initialize the chosenStylePrice and chosenColoursPrice locally inside their respective functions, when I should have had them declared globally. I had something similar yesterday when I was coding this, but I think I confused myself with a couple different techniques at once, and then I got all scambled. While I didn't need any CSS or HTML revisions, I did revise my JS using your answer, and it works as desired. Many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. While coding, keep in mind that "you are working with an imaginary thing" so you have to be very very careful: To keep the things always under control, you can apply very oriented and clean code like: first define variables, than functions, than statics and etc... but there must be some style rules. You will see the benefits immediately. Please upvote :D

Answer (score 1):

Your `calculateTotalPrice` function is taking two arguments, but you never supply two arguments to the function call.

When you have `calculateTotalPrice (chosenStyle = 0, chosenColours = 0)` and you pass `calculateTotalPrice(anyVariable)`, you will actually be setting `chosenStyle = anyVariable, chosenColours = 0` in that pass through the function.

You *could* call it like `calculateTotalPrice(chosenStyle,0)` and then later, `calculateTotalPrice(0,chosenColours)`, which would set the proper variable to the input you want, but you would still be miscalculating, since that would still set one of the values to `0`.

Instead, you need to pass the **current** value of the *opposite* dropdown each time.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. webmaster's reply solved my issue. But I'm a little conflicted. I feel like your reply actually answered my original question, whereas webmaster's reply helped to meet my goal.

Comment: I don't view this as a competition;  I did attempt to give you enough information to understand why you were having a problem, but I didn't provide actual fixed code.   Accept whichever answer you feel was more helpful; others can still read both answers if they have the same sort of issues in the future...

Comment: I find that many times, I learn as much as the person asking the question when I answer questions and write out explanations, so it is always valuable to me, and not about how many points I get from it.

Comment: I can certainly appreciate and respect that mode of thinking. I selected webmaster's response as my chosen answer, but please know that your response aided me, as well.